# Angular - HTTPClient put and post not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I have multiple services in my Angular Ionic App all copies of each other with the slightest changes.

I have a method like this (delete/update/get all work):

```js
endpoint = 'https://localhost:7183/api/CheckinData';
httpOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'content-Type': 'application/json' })};

clockIn(time, date) {
  const reply = new CheckinData();
  reply.userid = 2; //placeholder untill better authentication implementation
  reply.time = time;
  reply.date = date;
  this.create(reply);
}

create(data: CheckinData): Observable<any> {
  console.log('clockin', this.endpoint, JSON.stringify(data));
  return this.http.post(this.endpoint, JSON.stringify(data), this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError<CheckinData>('Error occured')));
}
```

I don't know if it is relevant but here is my `CheckinData` class:

```js
export class CheckinData 
{
  id: number;
  time: Time;
  date: Date;
  userid: number;
}
```

`console.log` works with return (-> method gets called):

> clockin https://localhost:7183/api/CheckinData {"userid":2,"time":"10 45 AM","date":"15 11 2022"}

There is no error.

But when I call get/ check in SSMS there is no new entry.

For example, this call works just fine (different service, different Api controller)

```js
create(todo: ToDo): Observable<any> {
  console.log('createToDo', this.endpoint, JSON.stringify(todo));
  return this.httpClient.post(this.endpoint, JSON.stringify(todo), this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError<ToDo>('Error occured')));
}
```

I can post with swagger/postman (-> API works).

I tried put instead of post and it doesn't work either.

There has to be another potential mistake I am missing.

If you have any ideas about what could be wrong/what else to check. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, I don't see your front-end side will submit the request to API. You need to [**subscribe the Observable**](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable#subscribing-to-observables) in order to submit the request.

```js
clockIn(time, date) {
  ...

  this.create(reply)
    .subscribe(x => {
      // Action after receive response from API
    });
}
```

Comment: Also make sure that you have done debugging by checking whether you have submitted the request and received the API response via browser DevTools (F12), Network tab. And also debug the API side by placing the breakpoint to check whether the API is hit and processed correctly for your implementation logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot I thought of subscribing like looking for a response not a way to deliver the values of my call.

Comment: Declaring Observable won't automatically execute (send the request to API) itself. But you need to subscribe to the Observable by providing the Observer in order to *execute the Observable*. I think the link that I shared in the answer will give you the concept of how Observable works.